# Issue with format when VBA runs automatically

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a vba code which runs automatically and after processing the data it sends the output table in outlook mail body.

The issue which i am facing is, the users who check this email in outlook are able to the table in the correct format but if the same mail is viewed on their gmail account they are not able to see the format and looks like plain text.

But this issue is not happening if i manually run macro. It only happens when macro runs automatically.

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim mailid As String
Dim Excelsheet As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim StrBody As String
Dim excelfile As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set rng = Sheets("Report").Range("B4:W55").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = xxxx
    .CC = xxxx
    .Subject = "xxxx"
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
'-----------------------------------
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2010
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook
Dim StrBody As String

StrBody = "Dear Team" & "<br>" & "" & "<br>" & _
              "Please find Group MTD Report" & "<br><br><br>"
TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
     .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
              "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried running this with the `On Error Resume Next` removed? That line is always a recipe for disaster as it could be hiding errors that you would otherwise be alerted to.

Comment: Thanks for the quick revert. I tried after removing the said code, did not get any error. Still mail body in outlook is perfect but when checked the same mail in gmail getting the issue with the format.

Comment: I have got a code ".BodyFormat = olFormatHTML" but using this code also did not get solution. Any one please help

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution for my issue.

It is simple, in the mentioned VBA code i made first .Display and then .Send. By running both the codes my problem solved.

Thanks guys..